# Symfony Security with Guard : User logged in and immediately logged out

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I want to authenticate users from a webservice. I created a firewall and I use **Guard** and a custom user provider.

Here is my problem : when I log in, the user is **authenticated and immediately logged out after the first redirection** (`web_profiler.intercept_redirects` at `true`helps me to deduce it).

I don't know what in my code or my config can be responsible of this. I created an authenticator that extends `AbstractGuardAuthenticator`. In the method `checkCredentials()`, I call the webservice and the answer is successful.

In `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method, I set a token given by the webservice in session and I redirect to the route the user was before the authentication is triggered. When the redirection is done, the user is no longer logged in.

I explored another point: my firewall is configured to work with specific hosts thanks to `host` key under my firewall configuration:

```
customer_account:
    pattern: ^(?!/admin[/]*).*$ # all but /admin
    host: "%extranet_domain_one%|%extranet_domain_two%"
    anonymous: ~
    provider: customer_account
    form_login:
        login_path: customer_account_login
        check_path: customer_account_login
    guard:
       authenticators:
           - app.customer_web_service_authenticator
    logout:
       path: customer_account_logout
       target: /
```

Here are my `access_control`config:

```
access_control:
        - { host: "%extranet_domain_one%|%extranet_domain_two%", path: ^/connexion, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { host: "%extranet_domain_one%|%extranet_domain_two%", path: ^/mot-de-passe, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { host: "%extranet_domain_one%|%extranet_domain_two%", path: ^/, roles: ROLE_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT }
```

In my provider, the method `loadUserByUsername()` returns a new user with the login and the token stored in session if it exists.

Any idea?

**Additional informations:**

`CustomerWebServiceAuthenticator`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Security\User\CustomerAccount;
use AppBundle\Security\User\CustomerAccountUserProvider;
use AppBundle\Services\Webservice;
use AppBundle\Services\MultisiteHelper;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class CustomerWebServiceAuthenticator
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Security
 */
class CustomerWebServiceAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{

    /** @var webservice */
    protected $webservice;

    /** @var MultisiteHelper */
    protected $multisiteHelper;

    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface */
    protected $router;

    /** @var SessionInterface */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * Indique si le site s'exécute en mode développement.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $dev;

    /**
     * Default message for authentication failure.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $failMessage = 'Mot de passe ou e-mail invalide';

    /**
     * WebServiceAuthenticator constructor.
     *
     * @param Webservice $webservice
     * @param MultisiteHelper  $multisiteHelper
     * @param RouterInterface  $router
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     * @param string $kernelEnvironment
     */
    public function __construct(
        Webservice $webservice,
        MultisiteHelper $multisiteHelper,
        RouterInterface $router,
        SessionInterface $session,
        $kernelEnvironment
    ) {
        $this->webservice = $webservice;
        $this->multisiteHelper  = $multisiteHelper;
        $this->router           = $router;
        $this->session          = $session;
        $this->dev              = $kernelEnvironment === 'dev';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $url = $request->getRequestUri();

        if ($url !== $this->router->generate('customer_account_login') || !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
            return null;
        }

        return [
            'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param mixed                 $credentials
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     *
     * @return CustomerAccount|null|UserInterface
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        if (!$userProvider instanceof CustomerAccountUserProvider) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username']);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException($this->failMessage);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param mixed         $credentials
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $xml = $this->webservice->loginCustomerAccount([
            'username'         => $credentials['username'],
            'password'         => ($credentials['password']),
        ]);

        if (isset($xml->identification) && isset($xml->identification['customer_id']) && isset($xml->identification['id_token_session'])) {
            /** @var $user CustomerAccount */
            $user
                ->setIdTokenSession((string) $xml->identification['id_token_session'])
                ->setCustomerId((string) $xml->identification['customer_id'])
            ;
            return true;
        }

        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException($this->failMessage);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        /** @var $user CustomerAccount */
        $user = $token->getUser();

        // Stockage en session, c'est ce qui maintient la connexion chez nous
        $this->session->clear();
        $this->session->set('customer_id', $user->getCustomerId());
        $this->session->set('id_token_session_customer', $user->getIdTokenSession());
        $this->session->set('login', $user->getUsername());

        // @todo LDA : adapter
        if ($this->session->has('_security.' . $providerKey . '.target_path')) {
            $url = $this->session->get('_security.' . $providerKey . '.target_path');
        } else {
            $url = $this->router->generate('customer_account_account');
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);
        $url = $this->router->generate('customer_account_login');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('customer_account_login');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with your guard authenticator.

Comment: @gp_sflover done. Thanks

Comment: Why do you clear the session inside `onAuthenticationSuccess`? The user  already have a valid authentication token.

Comment: In the symfony profiler you can access to the details of each instances. Take a look at the login instance (before and after the redirection) and you should be able to see the stack trace where is probably reported why the user was invalidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay: I found it!

There was a typo in `isEqualTo()` in my class `CustomerAccount` implementing `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`, so it can never return `true`.

Thanks for spending time helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Three problem is that you clear the session in `onAuthenticationSuccess`. If you want to implement your own logic about the generated token for authenticating you should implement `GuardAuthenticatorInterface` as said here http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#the-guard-authenticator-methods

> createAuthenticatedToken(UserInterface $user, string $providerKey) If
>   you are implementing the GuardAuthenticatorInterface instead of
>   extending the AbstractGuardAuthenticator class, you have to implement
>   this method. It will be called after a successful authentication to
>   create and return the token for the user, who was supplied as the
>   first argument